# Argument that Vandermonde matrix's determinant has $n-1$ distinct roots

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces, determinant

det(Vandermonde) = $\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}1 & x & x^2 & ... & x^{n-1} \\1 & a_2 & a^{2}_{2} & ... & a^{n-1}_{2} \\1 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\1 & a_n & a^2_{n} & ... & a^{n-1}_n\end{array}\right|$.

Let $P(x)$ be the polynomial in $x$ that you get from expanding along first row minors.

How do you show that $a_2, \dots, a_n$ are $n-1$ distinct roots of $P(x)$? How do I know that $a_2, \dots, a_n$ are distinct roots of this polynomial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** If two rows (or columns) of a matrix are the same then its determinant is 0.

Comment: I know this. I don't see how this helps?

Comment: Well $P(x)=\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}1 & x & x^2 & ... & x^{n-1} \\1 & a_2 & a^{2}_{2} & ... & a^{n-1}_{2} \\1 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\1 & a_n & a^2_{n} & ... & a^{n-1}_n\end{array}\right|$ so $P(a_i)=\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}1 & a_i & a_i^2 & ... & a_i^{n-1} \\1 & a_2 & a^{2}_{2} & ... & a^{n-1}_{2} \\1 & ... & ... & ... & ... \\1 & a_n & a^2_{n} & ... & a^{n-1}_n\end{array}\right|$. Can you see it now?

Comment: No, not really. I swear I'm not trying to be obtuse.

Comment: wait, if $i$ in $a_i$ is some integer from 2 to n, then the det = 0. Thus, P(a_i) is a root of P(x). Is this what you are going for?

Comment: @larry You're not being obtuse, but you're learning. A lot of people can seem obtuse: it must have happened to everyone to face something relatively simple but still can't solve it (happened to me two days ago ^^). Anyway, yes that's it: for any $i\in\{ 2,\ldots, n\}$ we have $\det =0$ because the row $(1\: a_i\: a_i^2\:\ldots\: a_i^{n-1})$ is repeated twice. Thus, $a_i$  **is a root of $P$, not $P(a_i)$**.